# Tomcat get killed by docker container due to memory outage

Tags: tomcat, docker, memory, jvm

I'm recently developing a rest service with tomcat. I set JAVA_OPTS = -Xmx1648m -Xmn1648 -server and make sure they already take effect. The docker is running with memory limit set to 4g.

The observation is that the memory usage by the tomcat process keeps growing, eventually to 4g. Then, the memory cost stays between 99% ~ 100% for time randomly between several minutes to hours. Then, the tomcat process crashes without any error like jvm heap oom.

I used jmap to dump the heap when the memory consumption observed by docker stats is around 3.5g. The dump file size is below 400m. Using mat to analyze the dump file shows most memory fraction actually could be garbage collected. I also manually run jcmd pid GC.run which largely reduced the memory usage (from 2g to 1.4g).

My inspection is that tomcat never reached the limit set by jvm, otherwise, there should be error log about jvm heap oom. Then, the memory should be consumed by jvm or other threads within tomcat. But I couldn't find a way to fix this problem. Please help!

Comment: Could you share the DockerFile that you're using?

Comment: On the other hand, be careful not everything that Java uses is heap memory. You should consider also the non heap. If you search for Java on-heap vs off-heap on any search engine you may find clues about the problem you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

When Xmx is set to 1648 ie 1.4G then JVM will not use more than that. If there is memory allocation issue then it could lead to OOM. When you say "memory cost stays between 99% ~ 100%" Do you mean RAM memory? In that case, what is your RAM Size? What is your task load?. Are you doing frequent I/O Operation?

Comment: Yes, RAM memory. The RAM size is limited by the docker container, i.e., 4g. The task load is indeed with frequent I/O. When a request is received, we do some MySQL insertions, and copy a file from its source path to a destination path.

Comment: RAM and Heap memory are the independent entity. There could be some operating system kill process when  it reaches the threshold and this issue has nothing to do with java heap. May be some OS limitation.